# How to get the block unique ID inside edit and save functions on registerBlockType

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to assign an unique ID into my SVG linearGradient element, this is for a custom Gutenberg block I'm working, basically I need to get access (or generate) an unique id so I can place it into the element HTML id parameter.

I know we have a main block ID we can do styles with CSS and create anchor too, but this is not helpful in what I'm trying to achieve.

I found this https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-compose/#withInstanceId but I don't understand how to use it, the docs does't have simple examples to me.

Follow here part of my block code (this does't works):

```
attributes: {
            id: {
                type: 'string',
                default: withInstanceId(function({instanceId}){ return instanceId })
            }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to assign the instance ID into an attribute so I can do access it into SAVE and EDIT functions with props.attributes.id

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I found this link with related content, but still can't achieve that: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/compose/src/hooks/use-instance-id

Comment: I don't think you want to drop it directly into the attribute like that. You probably want to save it as a local variable first.
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/compose/src/higher-order/with-instance-id

Answer (score 13):

To get a unique ID inside Gutenberg's `Edit` and `Save` Methods You can use `clientId` Props that provides inside `props` of Edit and Save Methods.

Example:

First Set Attribute:

```
attributes: {
   blockId: {
      type: 'string'
   }
}
```

Inside Edit method

```
edit: function( props ) {
    const { attributes, setAttributes, clientId } = props;
    const { blockId } = attributes;
    if ( ! blockId ) {
        setAttributes( { blockId: clientId } );
    }
}
```

**Since WP 5.8**, you need to wrap the function call with `useEffect`.

```
edit: function( props ) {
    const { attributes, setAttributes, clientId } = props;
    const { blockId } = attributes;

    React.useEffect( () => {
        if ( ! blockId ) {
            setAttributes( { blockId: clientId } );
        }
    }, [] );
}
```

Inside Save method

```
save: function( props ) {
    const { attributes } = props;
    const { blockId } = attributes;

    // So here `blockId` attribute will have a unique ID

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is helpful! The clientId should be typed as a "string" as it contains dashes. Otherwise you will get a validation error.

Comment: This was working fine with WP 5.7, but in 5.8 (react v16.3.1) we need to wrap the `setAttributes` call in `React.useEffect()`